# Add icon to ClickableText in JetpackCompose

Tags: text, icons, android-jetpack-compose

I have an AnnotatedString which I use in ClickableText:

```
val annotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(
            style = SpanStyle(
                color = colorResource(R.color.blue_color))
            )
        ) {
            append(text = "Some text here")
        }

ClickableText( text = annotatedText, maxLines = 2...)
```

Now I'd like to add an Icon at the end of my ClickableText. How could I do this?

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605986/add-icon-at-last-word-of-text-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: Thanks, I've found it already, but I'm dealing with ClickableText, not Text. Unfortunately there is no  inlineContent property in ClickableText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Current `ClickableText` doesn't support inlineContent. I think you can create one which look as same as `ClickableText` except it support `inlineContent` for adding the icon ([follow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611627/5381331)).

```
@Composable
fun CustomClickableText(
    ...
    inlineContent: Map<String, InlineTextContent> = mapOf(),
) {
    ...

    BasicText(
        ...,
        inlineContent = inlineContent
    )
}
```

This way help you easy to refactor if `ClickableText` support `inlineContent` in future.
Or, you can use `Text` with `Modifier.pointerInput` to handle click event.

Comment: Nice advice! Thanks a lot