# Avoiding line breaks in Inline Text Content in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to embed some custom icons (Image composable) in some paragraph text (Text composable). This is straightforward enough - this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611627/966538 gives an example of how to do this.

There is a number directly before the inline icon, and I want to prevent a linebreak between the number and the icon. E.g. 3Ψ - there should be no line break between the 3 and the Ψ, instead the whole thing should spill over to the following line.

I can't figure out how to accomplish this elegantly. What I have done so far is nest one placeholder inside another - the 'outer' placeholder is a Text composable itself, containing the prefix text and then the 'inner' placeholder is the image with the icon.

```
val iconContent = InlineTextContent(
    Placeholder(
        width = iconWidth,
        height = iconHeight,
        placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextBottom
    )
) {
    Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_foo), iconName)
}

val nestedStr = buildAnnotatedString {
    append(prefix)
    appendInlineContent("icon", "?")
}

val outerContent = InlineTextContent(
    Placeholder(
        width = totalWidth,
        height = totalHeight,
        placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextBottom
    )
) {
    Text(text=nestedStr, inlineContent = mapOf("icon" to iconContent), maxLines = 1)
}

val inlineContentMap = mapOf<String, InlineTextContent>("prefixedIcon", outerContent)

Text(annotatedString, inlineContent=inlineContentMap)
```

This works, however it seems fairly inelegant to be nesting Text components like this.

I should add - I'm parsing a marked up text file, so there are many instances of this and I don't know what they look like specifically ahead of time.

Is there a better way to prevent linebreaks between an inline image and some 'prefix' text?